# Why simple update where id=<pk> could lead to lock waits?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, locking

Trying to perform 2 updates to same table and same key (id as pk) and one of it die because of lock wait timeout. I can't understand how to solve it.

Hi here!
Please, could you explain me one easy thing. Feel like a dump to be honest.

mysql:8.2.0 in docker on herzner cloud instance.

1. I have a table:

```
create table if not exists arb.cross_exchange_current_orders_snapshot
(
    id          int auto_increment
        primary key,
    exchange_id int      not null,
    symbol_id   int      null,
    currency_id int      null,
    filter_id   int      null,
    bid         double   not null,
    bid_volume  double   null,
    ask         double   not null,
    ask_volume  double   null,
    timestamp   datetime not null,
    constraint FK_4C1F562238248176
        foreign key (currency_id) references arb.currency (id),
    constraint FK_4C1F562268AFD1A0
        foreign key (exchange_id) references arb.exchange (id),
    constraint FK_4C1F5622C0F75674
        foreign key (symbol_id) references arb.symbol (id),
    constraint FK_4C1F5622D395B25E
        foreign key (filter_id) references arb.cross_exchange_opportunity_filter (id)
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

2. performing update queries from my workers (around 150) in a concurrency way.
   Each update is something like

```
UPDATE arb.cross_exchange_current_orders_snapshot 
SET bid = '1.9715347482999', bid_volume = '507.21905909206', ask = '1.9717884658038', ask_volume = '507.15379329108', timestamp = '2024-02-10 20:47:09' 
WHERE id = 9101;
```

3. As we know in this case X lock needs to be granted and if it is not happening that means something keeping it.

After sometime I see that some of the queries waiting for a lock for 50 seconds.

QUESTION: Why the first one can't do his job (update) faster and release the lock for the second one.

Everytime I have 6-16 lock waiting queries from maybe 100 which is performed well and not visible in show process list at all.

Please, why?

---

When I started to investigate I went over different stuff even queries like that

```
select * from performance_schema.data_locks
         where LOCK_DATA in (
select LOCK_DATA from performance_schema.data_locks where LOCK_STATUS="WAITING")
```

And I confirmed my vision.
Every time I have 2 trans. One is waiting for the lock and second is keeping it.

Tried many stuff with mysql config, iostat and etc. Everything looks fine.

One interested thing is that right after restart of the mysql container for some short time (maybe 15min) everything works very-very fast.

Comment: Why is `ask` being set twice in your example?

Comment: What  is the value of `autocommit`?  If you use `BEGIN...COMMIT`, let's set the whole transaction.  I advise against setting autocommit=OFF; it's too easy to forget or sidestep the `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the transaction before which can't be commited because of some reason.
Thanks!